# Scipy normaltest returns masked

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, regression

I did

```
print scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest(errors)
```

and got

```
(masked, masked)
```

What does this mean? How do I recover the p-value from here? Is there an error that I am not aware of?

I also tried

```
print scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest(
 np.ma.masked_array(errors.values, errors.isnull()))
```

and it didn't help.
With some more experimentation, the test seems to work for `<50` samples, and always fails for more.

```
print errors.__class__, '\n', errors.head()

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 
0    0.002385
1    0.002455
2    0.002264
3    0.002476
4    0.002073
```

Comment: The functions in `mstats` are designed to deal with masked numpy arrays, not `pd.Series` objects. Try converting to a masked array first, e.g. `me = np.ma.masked_array(errors.values, errors.isnull())`.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. See edit.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without knowing more about what values `errors` contains. Are there NaNs or Infs? If so, are they masked? Can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?